# Vulkan Crash Program

Tags: c++, sdl, vulkan

I'm starting a game engine with Vulkan and SDL2. My program is crashing in a very specific part of my code. I'm really new in the Vulkan API and i have tried several modifications with no success. If someone could help me, here I give the full code and the part that I think it is crashing.

```
// GE_Base.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <glm.hpp>
#include <SDL_vulkan.h>
#include "GE_code_class.h"


#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        SDL_Log("Couldn't initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }   

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("GE_Base", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);

    ////////////////////////////////

    //VULKAN SETUP

    const char* instanceExtensionNames[] = {
        VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    };

    VkApplicationInfo ai = {};
    ai.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    ai.pNext = nullptr;
    ai.pApplicationName = "SDL Vulkan";
    ai.applicationVersion = 1;
    ai.pEngineName = "SDLV";
    ai.engineVersion = 1;
    ai.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 3);

    VkInstanceCreateInfo ici = {};
    ici.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    ici.pNext = nullptr;
    ici.flags = 0;
    ici.pApplicationInfo = &ai;
    ici.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    ici.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    ici.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
    ici.ppEnabledExtensionNames = nullptr;

    VkInstance instance;
    vkCreateInstance(&ici, nullptr, &instance);

    //CHECK PHYSICAL DEVICE (GRAFIC CARD)

    VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkPhysicalDevice);

    uint32_t deviceCount = 1;
    VkPhysicalDevice gpu;

    //VkPhysicalDevice *physical_devices = (VkPhysicalDevice*)malloc(sizeof(deviceCount)); 

    VkPhysicalDevice *physical_devices = (VkPhysicalDevice*)malloc(sizeof(deviceCount));
    vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &deviceCount, physical_devices);
    gpu = physical_devices[0];


    //CHECK QUEUE FAMILIES

    uint32_t graphics_queue_node_index;

    /*if (queue_props->queueCount <= 0) queue_props->queueCount = 1;*/

    uint32_t amountOfFamilies = 0;

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(gpu, &amountOfFamilies, NULL);
    VkQueueFamilyProperties *queue_props = new VkQueueFamilyProperties[amountOfFamilies];
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties(gpu, &amountOfFamilies, queue_props);
    assert(queue_props->queueCount >= 1);

    VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures features;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFeatures(gpu, &features);

    uint32_t graphicsQueueNodeIndex = UINT32_MAX;

    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < queue_props->queueCount; i++) {
        if ((queue_props[i].queueFlags & VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT) != 0) {
            if (graphicsQueueNodeIndex == UINT32_MAX)
                graphicsQueueNodeIndex = i;
        }
    }

    graphics_queue_node_index = graphicsQueueNodeIndex;

    //LOGICAL DEVICE

    VkDevice device;

    float queue_priorities[1] = { 0.0 };

    VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo q;

    q.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO,
    q.pNext = nullptr,
    q.queueFamilyIndex = graphics_queue_node_index,
    q.queueCount = 1,
    q.pQueuePriorities = queue_priorities;


    graphicsQueueNodeIndex = 2000;
    graphics_queue_node_index = graphicsQueueNodeIndex;

    //CREATE & INSTANTIATE DEVICE

    VkDeviceCreateInfo d;

    d.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO,
    d.pNext = nullptr,
    d.queueCreateInfoCount = 1,
    d.pQueueCreateInfos = &q,
    d.enabledLayerCount = 1,
    d.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr,
    d.enabledExtensionCount = 1,
    d.ppEnabledExtensionNames = (const char *const *) instanceExtensionNames,
    d.pEnabledFeatures = nullptr;

    vkCreateDevice(gpu, &d, nullptr, &device);

    //SURFACE WINDOW

    VkSurfaceKHR surface;

    SDL_Vulkan_CreateSurface(window, (SDL_vulkanInstance)&ici, (SDL_vulkanSurface*)&surface);

    //PRESENTATION QUEU

    VkBool32 *supportsPresent = new VkBool32[queue_props->queueCount];

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(gpu, queue_props->queueCount, surface, &supportsPresent[i]);
    graphics_queue_node_index = graphicsQueueNodeIndex;

    //QUEUE

    VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(VkQueue)

    VkQueue queu_;
    vkGetDeviceQueue(device, graphics_queue_node_index, queue_props->queueCount, &queu_);

    ////////////////////////////////

    GE_class *engine;

    engine = new GE_class();
    engine->Init(1280, 720);

    bool quit_app = false;

    while (!quit_app) {

        SDL_Event eve;

        while (SDL_PollEvent(&eve)) {

            switch (eve.type) {
            case SDL_WINDOWEVENT:
                if (eve.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED) {

                }
                break;
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit_app = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //double currentTime = (double)SDL_GetTicks() / 1000.0;
        //GLrender(currentTime);

        //double currentTime = (double) SDL_GetTicks() / 1000.0;
        //myRenderCode(currentTime);

        //SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        /*vkQueuePresentKHR()*/




    }

    //SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    //SDL_Quit();


    return 0;
}
```

> ```
>    VkQueue queu_;
>     vkGetDeviceQueue(device, graphics_queue_node_index, queue_props-queueCount, &queu_);
> ```

These are the lines that I think it's crashing. I guess in the previous lines I did
something wrong or I'm not initializing some variable. I'm not really sure.

Comment: You should enable some layers and setup debugging callbacks so that Vulkan can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `graphics_queue_node_index` is 2000 when you call `vkGetDeviceQueue`. That's most likely not a valid queue index.

```
VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo q;
// ...
q.queueFamilyIndex = graphics_queue_node_index,
// ...
graphicsQueueNodeIndex = 2000;
graphics_queue_node_index = graphicsQueueNodeIndex;
// ...
vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(gpu, queue_props->queueCount, surface, &supportsPresent[i]);
graphics_queue_node_index = graphicsQueueNodeIndex; // redundant?
// ...
vkGetDeviceQueue(device, graphics_queue_node_index, queue_props->queueCount, &queu_);
```